# Concept of multisig

Tags: solidity

Is this concept of multisig is right?

*Users first pay the contract that amount of eth which they wanst to send someone, and then owners will execute the transaction after verifying the user*

This is all i know about multisig concept. **Please tell me the main concept of multisig.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multisig is not only related to transfer ETH, but to any action that requires the authorization of multiple parties, identified by their wallet address.

You could achieve that action with an Smart Contract that keeps a mapping of needed wallet addresses.

When an authorized user execute a function, the Smart Contract will add that user's wallet address to the given votes, and whenever a new user votes/executes the function with their authorized address, the Smart Contract will check if all the required votes have been given. If so, it will execute the function when the last needed vote is given.

The concept is pretty simple, but it can be implemented in different ways.

Comment: Can u answer this question too https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/145160/help-me-to-pass-this-test

Comment: Yes sure but upvote the answer in this post if worked for you.

Comment: okay, done...send me ur telegram or discord so that i can send u the code

Comment: You can EDIT the initial question providing all the code. Then, it will work for the rest of the people with similar concerns. And it will also help if you provide a bit more of info about the purpose of the contract and the different functions.